# Why does Animate marginLeft does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm building a Slider but animating marginLeft does not work and i can't figure out why.

A Fade with Opacity doesn't work also.

```
  $currentSlide.find('.content').animate({
    marginLeft: '-100%',
    opacity: 0
  }, speed);

  setTimeout(function() {
    $currentSlide.removeClass('active');
    $nextSlide.addClass('active');

    $nextSlide.find('.content').animate({
      marginLeft: '0%',
      opacity: 1
    }, speed);
  }, speed);
```

Here you can see two Slides ( $currentSlide and $nextSlide ) where the first Slide should fade out with animating marginLeft to -100% and a second Slide that sould do that vice versa.

[edit] for sliding click on the white bars

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dpNRqQ

[edit]: the example is from me that doesn't but should work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

failure found:

change

```
$currentSlide.find('.content').animate
```

to

```
$currentSlide.find('.slide-content').animate
```